# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 kB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6473).

Comment: Is it true that you **increased the ad area** and **significantly cut down the allowed filesize**?!

Comment: Yes, it is true. They're technically independent changes but since they ultimately became folded in one update for a lot of sites... it does come out bizarre. Based on most of the ads I'm seeing get submitted for the new round, I'm going to see if I can bump up the requirements a little bit since we have a lot sitting in the 40-60KB range.

Comment: Can I ask **why**? Are the ads adding that much to people's internet traffic?

Comment: @GraceNote: When will these ads be available? I still see the old ones being displayed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Answer (score 45):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Earliest Detexify ad I know of](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013/11616#11616). [Inkscape SVG source for this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/detexify%20ad%202016.svg). Double the size for better display on retina devices.

Comment: Stole this one for [cs.SE](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1205/98). Thank you!

Answer (score 43):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: oi!​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌​

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥

Comment: And even some documented misfeatures. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: ooh! `:)`

Answer (score 35):

[image: TEXample.net]

Answer (score 34):

[image: TeX Live - cross-platform TeX software]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Visit our chatroom!]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Visit our chatroom!]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Visit our chatroom!]

Answer (score 30):

[image: PGFPlots Plot example gallery]

Comment: very handy reference, great work!

Answer (score 24):

[image: Overleaf - Free Online LaTeX Editor with Automatic Preview]

Answer (score 24):

[image: Papeeria: free online LaTeX editor]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Visit our chatroom!]

Comment: You wont lure many users to the Dark Side/ chatroom using my profile photo :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Nah, we will have lots of padawans. `:)`

Answer (score 22):

[image: CervanTeX: Spanish TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 21):

[image: TeXblog - News and ideas about TeX]

Answer (score 20):

[image: DANTE e.V. - German language TeX users group]

Comment: You have an extra `http://` at the beginning of the link URL.

Comment: @Zoxume Thank you! Fixed

Answer (score 20):

[image: TeX Users Group (TUG)]

Comment: i think i'd leave just a bit more space between the logo and the top/bottom frame edges.  right now, it looks artificial and a bit forced.  (going to be hard to overcome that, i'm afraid.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know! Quick shot before I have to go offline. I still can edit it a bit later if I got a better idea of adding the required frame without touching the logo. Feel free to change. I'd liked to add the TUG ad link quickly as it can already get votes when the question is fresh, as perhaps not everybody returns later to vote again.

Comment: sadly, my graphics competence `$< \epsilon$`.  i'll see if i can persuade someone else via the chat to poke at it.  thanks.

Answer (score 16):

[image: UK TeX FAQ - Questions and answers about TeX]

Answer (score 16):

[image: TUGboat: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Comment: A high-resolution picture of a monochromatic low-resolution scan, really? Also, if someone doesn’t already know what TUG Boat is why would they click on an advert that offers no further information on it?

Comment: Well, considering the image quality, this is the best I managed, I'm not a professional designer. Considering the absence of any text, I thought about it before and didn't find a good solution. If you have one, I'm fine with my picture being replaced, but I'd first want to know the opinion of barbara beeton with whom we discussed the ad before.

Comment: It was less a critique of your work than of TUG Boat’s design. You could improve the text, though, and perhaps remove the inner frame.

Answer (score 15):

[image: TeXwelt - Fragen und Antworten zu TeX auf Deutsch]

Comment: Just wondering if the enquoted sentence should have german quotes?

Comment: I think, that the slogan shouldn't be quoted at all.  Also the font looks extremely bitmapped.  Also the font should be Computer Modern (Sans or Roman).

Comment: @HenriMenke Retro :-) More seriously, it was quickly done during a 7d seatrial (test voyage) of an unfinished ship without satellite connection, just luckily having GSM shore connection because of passing an island. Sometimes temporary quick shots stay longer than intended - yes I should improve the graphic (done with GIMP text tool).

Answer (score 14):

[image: LaTeX Community Forum - Talk about TeX and LaTeX]

Answer (score 14):

[image: visit TeX.tips!]

Comment: Feel free to edit the ad if you make/get a better picture.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 13):

[image: comp.text.tex TeX Usenet group]

Answer (score 12):

[image: visit glossaries gallery]

Comment: I hope that's okay. I'm not trying to advocate brightly-coloured documents. It's just to show that it's possible to assign different formats to different categories of entries without hard-coding it into the entry definitions.

Comment: I think it's perfect!

Comment: @yo' Thanks :-)

Answer (score 12):

[image: 10th International ConTeXt meeting]

Answer (score 11):

[image: TeXstudio - LaTeX made comfortable]

Comment: Those colors, they hurt my eyes! The kerning is also odd. This ad is doing disservice to the software it tries to promote.

Comment: @Crissov please, don't blame the ad: this is the official logo of the software in question.

Answer (score 10):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from [2015](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5981/5763); the size is not a problem [anymore](https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad/pull/7).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Help writing and improving a wiki-book on LaTeX!]

Comment: [SVG source at Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LaTeX_wikibook_ad.svg)

Answer (score 6):

[image: LaTeX-шаблон для русской кандидатской диссертации и её автореферата (LaTeX template for russian PhD thesis)]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs]

Comment: Perhaps it should be a website instead of a google doc?

Comment: @RomainPicot Well that's the direct download link; as a Google docs add on, it has to be downloaded from a Google doc which redirects to the Google docs add-on store and this products page in specific.

Comment: This ad gives leaves me with no idea of what it’s promoting. Just a potentially shady link.

Comment: And "iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog" in link is really not making it more trustworthy.