# Our new ad series

Tags: discussion

Ladies and gentlemen, ducks and penguins, boys and girls of all ages!

As the Powers that Be decided to change the dimensions of the current ads, we decided to come up with a new ad series to promote our friendly chatroom, in which we talk about virtually everything but TeX. `:)`

[Community Promotion Ads - 2016](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/community-promotion-ads-2016)

This is the template we use, written in TeX, of course. `:)` The Polaroid code is provided by Paul Gaborit in his answer to [Polaroid photo effect in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195083/)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=300px,
  paperheight=250px,
  left=0.5cm,
  right=0.5cm,
  top=0.2cm,
  bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\drawborder[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\filldraw[line width=5mm, draw=#1, fill=#2] (current page.north west) -| (current page.south east) -| cycle;,
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,shadows,backgrounds,positioning}
\tikzset{
  polaroid/.cd,
  at/.store in=\polaroidat,
  at={0,0},
  graphics options/.store in=\polaroidgraphicsoptions,
  graphics options=,
  rotate/.store in=\polaroidrotate,
  rotate=0,
  caption/.store in=\polaroidcaption,
  caption=,
  caption distance/.store in=\polaroidcaptiondistance,
  caption distance=1mm,
  top margin/.store in=\polaroidtopmargin,
  bottom margin/.store in=\polaroidbottommargin,
  left margin/.store in=\polaroidleftmargin,
  right margin/.store in=\polaroidrightmargin,
  vmargin/.style={top margin=#1,bottom margin=#1},
  hmargin/.style={left margin=#1,right margin=#1},
  margin/.style={vmargin=#1,hmargin=#1},
  margin=.2cm,
  caption default/.style={font=\bfseries,node distance=1mm},
  caption options/.style={caption default/.append style={#1}},
  frame default/.style={draw,inner sep=0},
  frame options/.style={frame default/.append style={#1}},
}
\newcommand\polaroidset[1]{\tikzset{polaroid/.cd,#1}}
\newcommand\polaroid[2][]{
  \bgroup
  \tikzset{polaroid/.cd,#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\polaroidrotate{\polaroidrotate}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(\polaroidat)},rotate=\polaroidrotate]
    \node[rotate=\polaroidrotate,inner sep=0]
    (shoot) {\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\polaroidgraphicsoptions]{#2}};
    \path (shoot.north) ++(0,\polaroidtopmargin) coordinate (polaroid top);
    \path (shoot.south) ++(0,{-1*(\polaroidbottommargin)}) coordinate (polaroid bottom);
    \path (shoot.west) ++({-1*(\polaroidleftmargin)},0) coordinate (polaroid left);
    \path (shoot.east) ++(\polaroidrightmargin,0) coordinate (polaroid right);
    \node[rotate fit=\polaroidrotate,fit=(polaroid top)(polaroid bottom)(polaroid left)(polaroid right),polaroid/frame default]{};
    \node[rotate=\polaroidrotate,inner sep=0]
    (shoot) {\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\polaroidgraphicsoptions]{#2}};
    \coordinate (caption center) at ($(shoot.south)!-1 * \polaroidcaptiondistance!(shoot.north)$);
    \node[anchor=north,rotate=\polaroidrotate,polaroid/caption default]
    (caption) at (caption center) {\polaroidcaption};
  \end{scope}
  \egroup
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\drawborder{Wheat}{Wheat!30}

\centering\large Christian prefers\\ Arabic numbers.

\vspace{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \polaroid[rotate=-10,
  frame options={line width=1pt,draw,rounded corners=.5mm,fill=white,drop shadow},
  graphics options={width=1.5cm, height=1.5cm}]
  {example-image-a} % Christian's avatar
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}

What have \verb|{\the\roman}|s\\ ever done for us?

\vfill

{\Large Visit our chatroom!}

\end{document}
```

The resulting `.png` images are generated with this command:

```
$ convert -density 400 ad.pdf -scale 300x250 ad.png
```

If you prefer the old ads back, we can remove these new ones. `:)`

Comment: This post is also an ad for the other solutions to that question :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: ooh a meta-ad for ads. `:)`

Answer (score 15):

Do these ads actually work for anything? I don't see any point of having ads. We can instead hack them and put MWE requests, or practice tips such as

> **`minimal` is too minimal!!**

or

> **`\bf` is not your bff. `\it` is a cheater.**

and so on.

Comment: ooh I like this idea! `:)`